# BASH Not In Case

Tags: bash, case

I am trying to figure out a sane way to do a NOT clause in a case. The reason I am doing this is for
transcoding when a case is met, aka if I hit an avi, there's no reason to turn it into an avi again, I can
just move it out of the way (which is what the range at the base of my case *should* do). Anyway, I have some
*proto* code that I wrote out that kind of gives the gist of what I am trying to do.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 3); do 

    echo "trying: $i"

    case $i in
        ! 1)    echo "1" ;;     # echo 1 if we aren't 1
        ! 2)    echo "2" ;;     # echo 2 if we aren't 2
        ! 3)    echo "3" ;;     # echo 3 if we aren't 3
        [1-3]*) echo "! $i" ;;  # echo 1-3 if we are 1-3
    esac

    echo -e "\n"

done
```

expected results would be something like this

```
2 3 ! 1
1 3 ! 2
1 2 ! 3
```

Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You realize that `case` will, by design, only execute one thing per invocation?

Comment: ...as an additional aside, `$(seq 1 3)` isn't portable -- `seq` is not a POSIX-standardized command, and many platforms don't have it. Better to use a C-style loop, ie. `for ((i=1; i<=3; i++)); do`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did not, I thought it was more flexible like php etc

Comment: actually, the way bash's `case` works in the more common one; it's identical with the behavior of C and Java (except for lacking fallthrough, which is often considered confusing and a frequent source of bugs / misreading).

Comment: (Update to the above comment: bash's case now *does* have fallthrough available as of the 4.x series; it still behaves consistently with C, Java, &c. by only selecting a single entry point).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is contrary to the design of `case`, which executes only the first match. If you want to execute on multiple matches (and in your design, something which *is* `3` would want to execute on both `1` and `2`), then `case` is the wrong construct. Use multiple `if` blocks.

```
[[ $i = 1 ]] || echo "1"
[[ $i = 2 ]] || echo "2"
[[ $i = 3 ]] || echo "3"
[[ $i = [1-3]* ]] && echo "! $i"
```

Because case only executes the first match, it only makes sense to have a single "did-not-match" handler; this is what the `*)` fallthrough is for.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted, short if's work just as well, was actually just doing that in the background but you beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the extglob extension.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ case foo in !(bar)) echo hi;; esac
hi
$ case foo in !(foo)) echo hi;; esac
$
```

Comment: That won't behave as-desired with multiple patterns within the same case statement, though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah, true. Well, I'll leave it as-is, negative matching is still a useful thing to stumble upon.